# File upload error in PHP.

Tags: php, html, forms, file

```
<form method="post" action="upload_file.php">
Image:
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$targetfolder = "images/";
$targetfolder = $targetfolder . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']) ;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder))
{
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " is uploaded";
 }
 else {
 echo "Problem uploading file";
 }
 ?>
```

I have been working about this single file for hours but couldn't find any solution. File upload in PHP ini file is also on. Here is my codes.

Comment: Use in-built error features available for `$_FILES`, it may help you figure out what's wrong. http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Problem uploading file, which is in else echo.

Comment: @JahanzaibAsgher no that is what you've set it to show. Look at the link for more help.

Comment: @Script47 Thanks for your attention. My problem is solved using    enctype="multipart/form-data">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="upload_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

enc type missing in form.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasted a lot time ................... Once again thanks.

Comment: 3 mins to chose the answer.